# Proving that the Likelihood of a Normal Distribution is Not Non-Convex

Tags: normal-distribution

As a learning exercise (following from here [Why are Likelihood Functions from Exponential Family Convex?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636815/why-are-likelihood-functions-from-exponential-family-convex)), I want to try and prove that the likelihood function for a Normal Distribution is not non-convex.

Here is the Normal Distribution and its (Log) Likelihood:

$$
f(x; \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }
$$
$$
L(\mu, \sigma^2 | x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i; \mu, \sigma)
$$

$$L(μ, σ^2 | x) = -\frac{n}{2} \log(2π) - \frac{n}{2} \log(σ^2) - \frac{1}{2σ^2} ∑_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - μ)^2$$

Now, to prove that the Likelihood function is not non-convex, I need to show that all Eigenvalues for its Hessian (matrix of second derivatives) are either all positive, or either all negative. If the Eigenvalues are both positive and negative, the function is non-convex.

First I calculate the Jacobian (first derivatives):

$$\frac{∂L}{∂μ} = \frac{1}{σ^2} ∑_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - μ)$$
$$\frac{∂L}{∂σ^2} = -\frac{n}{2σ^2} + \frac{1}{2(σ^2)^2} ∑_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - μ)^2$$

$$J = [\frac{1}{σ^2} ∑_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - μ), -\frac{n}{2σ^2} + \frac{1}{2(σ^2)^2} ∑_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - μ)^2]$$

Now, I calculate the Hessian:

$$\frac{∂^2L}{∂μ^2} = -\frac{n}{σ^2}$$

$$\frac{∂^2L}{∂(σ^2)^2} = \frac{n}{2(σ^2)^2} - \frac{1}{(σ^2)^3} ∑_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - μ)^2$$

$$H = [-\frac{n}{σ^2}, 0; 0, \frac{n}{2(σ^2)^2} - \frac{1}{(σ^2)^3} ∑_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - μ)^2]$$

From here, I calculate the Eigenvalues - for a matrix $A$, the Eigenvalues are given by $det|A-\lambda I|$ . In a 2x2 Matrix (our Hessian), we have:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\lambda^2 - \lambda(a+d) + (ad-bc) = 0
$$

This function will have two roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$:

$$
\lambda_1 = -\frac{n}{\sigma^2}, \quad \lambda_2 = \frac{n}{2(\sigma^2)^2} - \frac{1}{(\sigma^2)^3} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)^2
$$

It is not clear immediately if the second term in $\lambda_2$ is larger than the first term in $\lambda_2$. If the second term was indeed bigger than the first term, then $\lambda_2$ would be negative.

If we use the argument that:

$$
s^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)^2
$$

$$
n s^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)^2
$$

$$E(s^2) = \sigma^2$$

Then we could say:

$$E[(x_i - μ)^2] = nσ^2$$
$$\lambda_2 = \frac{n}{2(\sigma^2)^2} - \frac{1}{(\sigma^2)^3} n\sigma^2 = \frac{n}{2(\sigma^2)^2} - \frac{n}{(\sigma^2)^2} = -\frac{n}{2} \frac{1}{(\sigma^2)^2}$$

Thus, $\lambda_2$ is approximately negative under expectation.

So, we could say that both eigenvalues are negative which show that the likelihood function is concave. As I understand, from an optimization perspective, optimizing a concave function is the same as optimizing a convex function.

The concerning case would be when the eigenvalues are both positive and negative, suggesting  that the function is non-convex (i.e. multiple local minima) and a potentially difficult problem to optimize.

Is my analysis correct?